# What causes Acrobat "An error exists on this page" with PDF maps from ArcGIS 10.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, arcgis-10.3, pdf

After exporting a map as PDF in ArcGIS 10.3, the following error shows up in Adobe Acrobat:

> "An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem."

In the map, there is as well a lack of some features or at least feature parts.

Creating PDFs is a very basic requirement.

Do you know any patch or workaround for this, or do I have to go a version back to 10.2?

Comment: Mention steps for how are you exporting your maps.

Comment: Via "File -> Export Map". Best quality settings and a DPI value between 96 and 600. Destination Colorspace is RGB. 'Compress Vectorgraphics' is checked. Image compression: Adaptive.

Comment: What version of Adobe Acrobat Reader are you using?  What happens when you experiment with modifying the settings, or modifying the layers which are turned on?  Be sure to use the [edit] button rather than a comment trail to address any requests for clarifications.  I export lots of PDFs from ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop to Adobe Acrobat Reader DC Version 2015.009.20077 (and earlier versions) without a problem.  I would be surprised if this turned out to be a 10.2/10.3 version difference.

Comment: The same issue arise after installing patch UTU5 on the ArcGis 10.2.1

Comment: You might run a repair geometry on your layers, at least the ones that aren't showing up correctly.

Comment: It seems to be a known issue for users who use ArcGIS in computer environments which are not configured completely in English:
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/118932

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem with ArcGIS 10.2.1 Utility and Telecom Patch 5. Issue is registered as BUG-000083717 and resolved in the following patch 
http://support.esri.com/download/6422 but also fixed in Utility and Telecom Patch 6.